# Mongodb: aggregate array of integers for each array position without map/reduce

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB. I am wondering if it is possible to aggregate each "column" in array. Assume we have below documents:

```
db.test.insert([{"player": "A", "year": 2010, "value": [1, 1 ]},
                {"player": "A", "year": 2011, "value": [2, 1 ]},
                {"player": "A", "year": 2012, "value": [2, 1 ]},
                {"player": "B", "year": 2010, "value": [1, 2 ]}])
```

The expected result should be like :

```
      [
        {
        "player": "A",
        "sum_result": [
            5,
            3
        ]
        },
        {
        "player": "B",
        "sum_result": [
            1,
            2
        ]
        }
    ]
```

Is it possible to do that without using Map/Reduce? Below link shows a map/reduce solution, but I am seeking an alternative way to achieve the same goal. Thanks!

[Mongodb: aggregate array of integers for each array position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827656/mongodb-aggregate-array-of-integers-for-each-array-position)

Comment: Why is the working solution not good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the problems can be solved in aggregation only if the elements in the document, involved, *can be reached by a path name*.

In this example the `values` array elements **cannot** be reached by the path `values.0` or `values.1`.

Hence to solve such problems you need to go for `map-reduce`, which provides more flexibility.

Unfortunately you cannot get the desired output using aggregation in this case, unless you change your schema. One such examples would be to make the `values` field - an array of documents. Here all the elements in the values array can be reached by a *path name* such as `values.c1` (denoting values in column `1`)

```
db.t.insert([ 
{"player":"A","year":2010,"value":[ {"c1":1}, {"c2":1}]},
{"player":"A","year":2011,"value":[ {"c1":2}, {"c2":1}]},
{"player":"A","year":2012,"value":[ {"c1":2}, {"c2":1}]},
{"player":"B","year":2010,"value":[ {"c1":1}, {"c2":2}]}
])
```

Then you could aggregate it as below:

```
db.t.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$value"},
{$group:{"_id":"$player",
         "c1":{$sum:"$value.c1"},
         "c2":{$sum:"$value.c2"}}},
{$group:{"_id":"$_id",
         "c1":{$push:{"c1":"$c1"}},
         "c2":{$push:{"c2":"$c2"}}}},
{$project:{"value":{$setUnion:["$c1","$c2"]}}}
])
```

o/p:

```
{ "_id" : "A", "value" : [ { "c1" : 5 }, { "c2" : 3 } ] }
{ "_id" : "B", "value" : [ { "c2" : 2 }, { "c1" : 1 } ] }
```

Since the solution involves the [**$unwind**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operation, which is costly, i suggest you to measure the performance of both the solutions against your data set and choose the one which best suits your application.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. Changing the schema could be the best way for this problem. As you pointed, **$unwind** operation might be costly. I eventually decided to use below solution.

Revised document:

```
db.test.insert([{"player": "A", "year": 2010, "values": {"v1":1, "v2":1 }},
                {"player": "A", "year": 2011, "values": {"v1":2, "v2":1 }},
                {"player": "A", "year": 2012, "values": {"v1":2, "v2":1 }},
                {"player": "B", "year": 2010, "values": {"v1":1, "v2":2 }}])
```

Query statement:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$group:{"_id":"$player", 
             "v1":{$sum:"$values.v1"},
             "v2":{$sum:"$values.v2"}}},
    {$project:{"values":{"v1":"$v1","v2":"$v2"}}}
])
```

Output:

```
{
    "result": [{
        "_id": "B",
        "values": {
            "v1": 1,
            "v2": 2
        }
    }, {
        "_id": "A",
        "values": {
            "v1": 5,
            "v2": 3
        }
    }],
    "ok": 1
}
```